# Detect equidistant lines on an image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect horizontal distance markers on a measurement plate like on the picture below. The marked area shows which lines I need to detect. You will notice there is a problem in the image, an extra line (marked with an arrow) that should not be there - it's just an artifact and it's messing with my initial algorithm to detect the "true lines" (the lines that have corresponding numbers to the left).

[image: plate]

With kernel density estimation, I can establish what is the most common distance between the consecutive lines, e.g. 150 pixels. I am later looping through all lines, trying to find candidates for the ruler lines. The algorithm:

```py
margin = 30 # in pixels
ruler_distance = 150 # established with kernel density estimation, we could use median too
candidates = defaultdict(list)
for i, line1 in enumerate(merged):
    candidates[i].append(line1)
    for j, line2 in enumerate(merged):
        if j > i:
            avg_y1 = (line1[1] + line1[3]) / 2 # line[1] and line[3] are y-coordinates
            avg_y2 = (line2[1] + line2[3]) / 2
            diff = avg_y2 - avg_y1 
            if ruler_distance - margin <= diff <= ruler_distance + margin:
                candidates[i].append(line2)
                ruler_distance = diff + avg_ruler_distance
```

The trouble is, the algorithm is very volatile. It works for `margin=30`, but if I change it by +/- 10, it will fall apart. Obviously the issue is perspective. The lines are equidistant in reality, but not with perspective.

Maybe I need a radically different approach? The presented image is a result of detecting horizontal lines, merging them together and finding coordinates with Hough transform (in OpenCV). It could be tempting to further erode the marked line, but following this method leads to eliminating some markers in other images.

Data (can be read with e.g. `numpy.loadtxt`):

```
23 18 882 17
1449 445 2841 454
508 625 1887 645
746 655 2092 670
548 1140 1998 1140
692 1180 1739 1180
480 1362 892 1362
807 1988 1234 1988
795 2116 1575 2116
783 2254 1717 2254
770 2395 1882 2395
756 2542 1878 2542
1008 2607 1332 2607
742 2695 1892 2695
729 2854 1900 2854
715 3016 1907 3016
387 3531 1949 3533
1515 4026 3023 4008
```

Comment: Because of perspective forshortening they might not be equidistant in the image. If that effect is small enough you could use a RANSAC approach (create random pair candidates and count the number of inliers) or use a smarter approach to save processing time (select candidates not randomly but from their neighborhood).

Comment: If you are not able to correct perspective with a homography, maybe cross-ratio can help. Google for cross-ratio rays

Comment: @Micka Thanks, can you elaborate on how you would use RANSAC? Homography would be of great help, but I cannot count on having the aforementioned plate in a nice, perpendicular orientation. My current thinking is, if nothing works, first detect the digits and then find lines from there (currently I detect lines first and then look for digits).

Comment: 1. detect lines 2. Repeat until no bigger number of inliers can be expected. 3. Draw two of the lines randomly 4. compute distance between them 5. For that computed distance check which other lines agree to that distance (are inlier). 6. Remember the highes number of inliers.

Comment: At point 3 you could also draw 3 lines randomly and use them to estimate the perspective effect (cross-ratio) and then when checking for inliers apply the same cross-ratio.